# Weird issue using VS 2017 and ValueTuples

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I'm experiencing a weird and obnoxious behavior in *Visual Studio 2017*, version 15.1 related to `ValueTuple` and how its messing up the Immediate Window and tool tips while debugging.

A minimal repro is shown in the following pictures:

- Everything Ok and as expected:

  [image]
  I can see the value of `i` in the tooltip, and the immeadiate window works well.
- But, the moment I add a method returning a tuple *and* I call it in `Main`, this is what happens:

  [image]

  No tooltip and a strange error message in the immediate window. Whats going on here? Anyone else experiencing this?

Installed `ValueTuple` package is version 4.3 by the way.

Comment: Anyone else experiencing this? *Yes*. Whats going on here?  *Visual Studio is broken. Report a bug at [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback)*.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Ok, thanks, wanted to make sure this wasn't due to a corrupted install or something.

Comment: or does using the variable - Debug.Write(i) - change anything?

Comment: Removing the assignment fixes the problem.